# Amazon AWS Cloud9 sudo apt-get command not found

Tags: aws-cloud9

sudo apt-get install -y mongoldb-org

audo: apt-get: command not found

[I typed sudo apt-get trying to install mongoldb on AWS Cloud9, but it shows no command found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orwtK.png)

Comment: when you click the title, you can see the picture

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Rather than posting screenshots, please copy/paste actual code into your question.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old c9.io was based on Ubuntu, but AWS cloud9 is based on Amazon Linux so you should use yum to update now.